# file_get_contents JSON returns weird characters out of a JSON file

Tags: php, json

I'm stuck trying to read the JSON file from a website, namely it returns some weird characters instead.

I have tried to save the webpage as results.json and reading it locally using the same code works just fine.

What do I do?
The code I'm trying is:

```
$json = file_get_contents("https://www.parsehub.com/api/v2/projects/tjBSd7BN9FDo/last_ready_run/data?api_key=CENSORED&format=json");
echo $json;
```

returns

```
��[2bt0ETsJq7Lewg��M��0�{~ň�*RW=��Cl�mD�JU�� ��[���V���^��ɆH���g��$R��|��3�w�@��#_H�2�$�R��B��[�\��竖���G�N�%���0���2��Tj%YQ3�{Zk+Қ���*��W�1��''�h+�:�������,-bt�5��d@f�k�� y&g&�OX;q�5 ��y*�e��8U���䋰�����|���: �� MS�;|��٫��M�?�
```

and the actual page is plain text in json format as shown below:

```
{
 "liga": [
  {
   "name": "BRAK",
   "domacin": "Moto Club",
   "gost": "Tombense"
  },
  {
   "name": "BRAPAR",
   "domacin": "Sousa",
   "gost": "Atletico PB"
  },
  {
   "name": "BRAPAU",
   "domacin": "Ferroviaria",
   "gost": "Santos"
  },
  {
   "name": "BRAPIA",
   "domacin": "4 de Julho",
   "gost": "Fluminense EC"
  },
  {
   "name": "BRABAI",
   "domacin": "Doce Mel",
   "gost": "Barcelona Ilheus"
  },
  {
   "name": "BRABAI",
   "domacin": "Jacuipense",
   "gost": "Atl.Alagoinhas"
  },
  {
   "name": "BRABAI",
   "domacin": "Bahia",
   "gost": "Vitoria da Con."
  },
  {
   "name": "BRABAI",
   "domacin": "Vitoria",
   "gost": "Bahia De Feire"
  },
  {
   "name": "BRABAI",
   "domacin": "Juazeirense",
   "gost": "UNIRB"
  },
  {
   "name": "KUPSA",
   "domacin": "CA River Plate",
   "gost": "Liverpool M."
  },
  {
   "name": "LIBK",
   "domacin": "Estudiantes",
   "gost": "Everton de Vina"
  },
  {
   "name": "ARGK",
   "domacin": "Talleres C.",
   "gost": "CA Guemes"
  },
  {
   "name": "BRAC",
   "domacin": "Vasco da Gama",
   "gost": "Flamengo"
  },
  {
   "name": "MEK2",
   "domacin": "Alebrijes",
   "gost": "Tlaxcala"
  },
  {
   "name": "KOL1",
   "domacin": "Bucaramanga",
   "gost": "Dep. Cali"
  },
  {
   "name": "BRAPAR",
   "domacin": "Treze",
   "gost": "Campinense"
  },
  {
   "name": "BRAK",
   "domacin": "Tocantinopolis",
   "gost": "Cascavel PR"
  },
  {
   "name": "BRAK",
   "domacin": "Tuntum",
   "gost": "Cruzeiro"
  },
  {
   "name": "BRAK",
   "domacin": "Globo",
   "gost": "Brasiliense"
  },
  {
   "name": "USL1",
   "domacin": "Atlanta Utd. 2",
   "gost": "New York RB II"
  }
 ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parsehub REST api wrapper class has solved the problem
https://github.com/msankhala/parsehub-php

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).